# Insufficient Permission code 403 on Upload

Tags: objective-c, google-drive-api

Using the Quickstart app for iOS I was able to get Google Drive browsing files and folders, displaying icons and thumbnails, and downloading files.  However, when it comes to uploading I get the following error:

**An error occurred: Error Domain=com.google.GTLRErrorObjectDomain Code=403 "Insufficient Permission" UserInfo={GTLRStructuredError=GTLRErrorObject 0x61800024ff90: {message:"Insufficient Permission" errors:[1] code:403}, NSLocalizedDescription=Insufficient Permission}**

From the comments here and on the Google forum it seems I need to use the Drive scope but I can't figure out how to do that.  Here's the callback from the sign-in:

```
- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn didSignInForUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user withError:(NSError *)error {
    if (error != nil) {
        [self showAlert:@"Authentication Error" message:error.localizedDescription];
        _driveService.authorizer = nil;
    } else {
        self.signInButton.hidden = true;
        _driveService.authorizer = user.authentication.fetcherAuthorizer;
        [self signedIn];
        [self listFilesFromFolderID:[self initialFolder]];
    }
}
```

Then, to upload the file I'm doing this:

```
_driveFile = [GTLRDrive_File object];
_driveFile.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", _filenameToSave, _fileExtension];
_driveFile.mimeType = _fileMimeType;

NSString *parentRef = @"root";

if ( self.currentFolder )
    parentRef = [self.currentFolder.identifier copy];

_driveFile.parents = @[ parentRef ];

GTLRUploadParameters *uploadParameters = [GTLRUploadParameters uploadParametersWithData:fileData
                                                                               MIMEType:_driveFile.mimeType];
uploadParameters.shouldUploadWithSingleRequest = TRUE;
GTLRDriveQuery_FilesCreate *query = [GTLRDriveQuery_FilesCreate queryWithObject:_driveFile
                                                               uploadParameters:uploadParameters];
query.fields = @"id";
[self.driveService executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLRServiceTicket *ticket,
                                                     GTLRDrive_File *file,
                                                     NSError *error) {
    if (error == nil) {
        NSLog(@"File ID %@", file.identifier);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 8):

The issue is in given permission while doing SignIn into Google. Kindly check **scopes** which you gave during sign-in.

```
GIDSignIn* signIn = [GIDSignIn sharedInstance];
signIn.delegate = self;
signIn.uiDelegate = self;
signIn.scopes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:kGTLRAuthScopeDrive, nil];
```

Changes:

```
kGTLRAuthScopeDriveReadonly --> kGTLRAuthScopeDrive
```

I put it kGTLRAuthScopeDriveReadonly and getting the same error. Just check with code about same.

Comment: Thank you so much!  It was right under my nose.  I spent hours in the Google documentation trying to figure that out.  Duh.

Comment: @user1673447 I recently did it and also spend spent much more time behind it.  Is my answer helpful to you?